# Как прописать путь к файлу CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Файл index.html видит CSS файл style.css, при этом когда прописываю путь к тому же CSS файлу но из другого html-файла, то он его не видит (на странице сайта ничего не применяется), перебрал уже несколько вариантов, но так и не понял как его верно подключить, подскажите в чем я ошибся.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путь прописывается относительный. В вашем случае нужно выйти из текущей директории с помощью ".."

```
"../css/style.css"
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал это, но только заметил, что ставил вместо двух точек три, все заработало, благодарствую.